# Kivy Event on carousel when slide change

Tags: python, carousel, kivy

I don't have any idea to find a solution of my problem.

I have make an application with Carousel Widget. In this Carousel I have 4 slides. 
welcomeSlide -> DVDSlide -> DVDPretSlide --> CategorySlide
I have make a class for each slides.

I use a ListAdpter to display the data extracted from an Sqlite3 Database.

My pblem is about the refresh of the list, when I modify a DVD (add name to pret) in the DVDSlide, when I slide to the DVDPret, the DVD do not appears because the List is not refresh.

Like the doccumentation for the carousel I don't find the event when slide change. It will be the best if an event exist to get the current slide index.

Have you got any Idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can observe `index` property:

```
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<Page>:
    Label:
        text: str(id(root))

<Carousel>
    on_index: print("slide #{}".format(args[1]))
''')

class Page(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Carousel()
        for x in range(10):
            root.add_widget(Page())
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Or you can observe `current_slide` property:

```
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<Page>:
    label_id: label_id
    Label:
        id: label_id
        text: str(id(root))

<Carousel>
    on_current_slide: print(args[1].label_id.text)
''')

class Page(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Carousel()
        for x in range(10):
            root.add_widget(Page())
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: `on_index` is great.  Where did you find this?  I can't see it anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: @JohnBaber-Lucero, `index` is a property described [here](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.carousel.html#kivy.uix.carousel.Carousel.index) and for any property you can define `on_<PROPERTY NAME>` method to observe its changes. See [here](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#observe-property-changes) for more reference. This is what makes Kivy properties so useful.

Comment: I found that neither `on_index` nor `on_current_slide` doesn't work. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure python solution rather than a Kivy Language solution you can create your own carousel that inherits from the Kivy carousel as follows.

```
import kivy      
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel 

class MyCarousel(Carousel):
    # This class is a carousel that runs script
    # when a slide gets focus (except first load).
    def on_index(self, *args):
        print('the slide is', self.index)
        # YOUR CODE GOES HERE
        Carousel.on_index(self, *args)
```